Does embedding Qt resources affect RAM consumption?
I'm working on a Qt application where I'm embedding all resources by default into the binariy files using the Qt Resource System. I understand that this approach can simplify distribution by bundling resources with the executable. However, I'm concerned about its impact on RAM consumption at runtime.
I want to ensure that my application remains memory efficient, especially when dealing with large amounts of resource files (images, translations). If embedding resources into C++ files does increase RAM usage, are there any strategies or best practices I should follow to mitigate this impact?

I believe embedded resources are considered part of the program and are loaded into RAM just like everything else.  But I don't have any proof so I can't leave an answer.

Possibly related to Is an entire static program loaded into memory when launched?. In theory, the resources won't be loaded into RAM until they are actually requested. You can easily test it on your own: create 2 identical programs, each one including a different resource (for instance, an uncompressed large image, and an icon), but do not load that resource at runtime; the executable will obviously have different sizes, but the RAM usage should probably be similar as soon as the files are not loaded.

depends on your OS, which one are you using?

The three major desktop platforms @AlanBirtles
